# ASP File upload control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, asyncfileupload

I am using dynamic ajax file upload control. 
AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload()

While i am trying to upload file, in page load the
value of `Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]` is, "`AsyncFileUploadID=MainContent_flbFileUpload1&rnd=01846502097323537`".

Can anyone tell me, why this happens?

Comment: Please specify what control you using, there are many out there for file upload.

Comment: i am using dynamic AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AsyncFileUpload.pre.js` file found in [**`ajaxcontroltoolkit.zip`**](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/AspDotNet_Free_Code/Ajax_Control/Download_AJAX_Control_Toolkit.htm) and  in `_onload: function (e) { .... }` has below sample lines which create the resulting postback URL as:

```
mainForm.action = url + 'AsyncFileUploadID=' + this.get_element().id + '&rnd=' 
                  + Math.random().toString().replace(/\./g, "");

mainForm.target = this._iframeName;
```